# What is the merit of the "function" type (not "pointer to function")

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

Reading the C++ Standard, i see that there are "function" types and "pointer to function" types:

```
typedef int func(int);     // function
typedef int (*pfunc)(int); // pointer to function
typedef func* pfunc;       // same as above
```

I have never seen the function types used outside of examples (or maybe i didn't recognize their usage?). Some examples:

```
func increase, decrease;            // declares two functions
int increase(int), decrease(int);   // same as above

int increase(int x) {return x + 1;} // cannot use the typedef when defining functions
int decrease(int x) {return x - 1;} // cannot use the typedef when defining functions

struct mystruct
{
    func add, subtract, multiply;   // declares three member functions
    int member;
};

int mystruct::add(int x) {return x + member;} // cannot use the typedef
int mystruct::subtract(int x) {return x - member;}

int main()
{
    func k; // the syntax is correct but the variable k is useless!
    mystruct myobject;
    myobject.member = 4;

    cout << increase(5) << ' ' << decrease(5) << '\n'; // outputs 6 and 4
    cout << myobject.add(5) << ' ' << myobject.subtract(5) << '\n'; // 9 and 1
}
```

Seeing that the function types support syntax that doesn't appear in C (declaring member functions), i guess they are not just a part of C baggage that C++ has to support for backward compatibility.

So is there any use for function types, other than demonstrating some funky syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of why this is useful is [boost](http://www.boost.org), where you see this a lot. For example in the signals2 library:

```
boost::signals2::signal<void (int, int)> MySignal;
```

where the above declares a signal that will accept any function that takes two ints and has a void return type.

Answer (score 4):

On the one hand, you seem to be talking about function types in general. On the other hand, it appears that your question is really about the usability of *typedef names* for function types.

The *function types* themselves is a fundamental concept built into both C and C++ languages. They are used all the time. You just can't live without them. Every time you declare a function you declare an entity of function type. Every time you use a pointer to a function, you use a pointer to function type. Etc.

As for the possibility of making *typedef names* for function types... I don't see much use for it. It is, I think, a part of C baggage, that was extended a bit for C++ just because it was easy to do.

As you correctly noted typedef names for function types can be used to declare member functions (and in C++ you can also include `const` specifier into typedef, as in `typedef int MemberType() const;`), but, for example, you can't use this feature with function types passed as template parameters.

Comment: actually, given the awkward syntax of function types, I usually typedef them in order to gain in readability. But then, I also typedef STL containers, I guess I am lazy :)

Answer (score 0):

boost:function uses that syntax, called "preferred" syntax.
Seems that kind of syntax is not widely used? Comparing to function pointer.

Comment: Please make your answer readable. If you do, I'll vote this up since Boost.functions actually a good reason to use this typedef.

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed my message was messed. Edited it.

Comment: anatolyg did say function type is not used widely other than function pointer type is. Please read carefully.

Comment: I'd prefer that syntax for the `unary_function` / `binary_function` template argument. Otherwise I can't remember whether the result type should be given first or last (and the compiler doesn't care, since the typedefs are normally unused anyway). Also, this syntax is adopted for `std::function`: makes most sense, since the object can be "called" as if it had the given signature.

Answer (score 0):

You see it in the new function objects in Boost/TR1/C++0x.

`std::function<void()>` accepts any object with an operator() that returns void and takes no arguments.